# extract information about vmware host from within the guest

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have virtual machine (guest) running inside VMware Hypervisor (host).

The guest is running Debian and has vmware tools installed

How can I extract as much information as possible about the host, from within the guest?

Specifically, I would like to extract identifying information about the host, so that I can recognize whether I am running inside the same host, or whether the vm has been migrated to another.

Comment: *should* not be possible.

Comment: maybe with VMCI? https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vmci-sdk/